# Publisher vba select shape and set size and location

Tags: vba, publisher

It seems simple enough... I have 100 pages with 2 graphics on each one. All I want to do is click on one graphic and change its size and location, then the second graphic, the same but different location. Then move to next page and repeat. I cannot get anything to happen...

```vb
Sub LeftPage()
    Dim LeftPage As Shape
    Set LeftPage = ActivePage.Shapes.ShapeRange(1)
    With LeftPage(Left:=0, Top:=0, Width:=5.5, Height:=8.5)
    End With
End Sub

Sub RightPage()
    Dim RightPage As Shape
    Set RightPage = ActivePage.Shapes.Range(1)
    With RightPage(Left:=5.5, Top:=0, Width:=5.5, Height:=8.5)
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I don't have Pulisher to test the code. The code should be like `With LeftPage
    .Left = 0
    .Top = 0
    .Width = 5.5
    .Height = 8.5
End With`